# assign class variables for inherited classes

Tags: ruby

When inheriting a class, I want to save class variables to the *inheriting* class instead of the parent class... like so...

```
class Foo
  def self.inherited klass
    klass.title = klass.to_s
  end

  def self.title= title
    @@title = title
  end

  def self.title
    @@title
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
end

class Baz < Foo
end

Bar.title # returns `Baz` instead of `Bar`
Baz.title
```

This is a contrived example because after playing around with it, I more want to just understand than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the class variable to instance variable.

```
class Foo
  def self.inherited klass
    klass.title = klass.to_s
  end

  def self.title= title
    @title = title
  end

  def self.title
    @title
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
end

class Baz < Foo
end

Bar.title  # => "Bar"
Baz.title # => "Baz"
```

`@@title` class variable is a shared variable. `Baz`, `Bar` and `Foo` all are using the same class variable `@@title`. When you did `class Baz < Foo ;end`, then `@@title` has been updated to the name of `Baz`, thus all call to the getter method `#title` is giving currently updated value of the variable `@title`.

Follow the code below :-

```
class Foo
  def self.inherited klass
    klass.title = klass.to_s
  end

  def self.title= title
    @@title = title
  end

  def self.title
    @@title
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
end

# see the output here
Bar.title # => "Bar"

class Baz < Foo
end

# here the output changed, as @@title value is holding the currently updated
#value
Bar.title  # => "Baz"
Baz.title # => "Baz"
```

Comment: so what i am trying to understand is why all 3 classes share the same class variable.  i had originally been using an instance variable, but it seemed counter-intuitive because it implied that those variables would be available for instances of the classes.... but since its a class method, the instance variable references the class (an instance of the `Class` class?

Comment: @brewster This is how it is designed.. *class variables* will be shared. Why the design, I don't know. But I can assure how, this is how it behaves. :-)

Comment: i mean since there are technically 3 classes being declared, i was trying to understand why i could not declare 3 independent class variables between them.

Comment: @brewster You can do it using instance variables. If you want, then you need to use different class variables ( means their names should be different). I understand what your next question is, which has been asked earlier in SO. I answered it also, but not able to find it now :-(. If you want, you can search it from my all accepted answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [Module#class_variable_get](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_get) and [Module#class_variable_set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-class_variable_set):

```
class Foo
  def self.title= title
    class_variable_set(:@@title, title)
  end
  def self.title
    class_variable_get(:@@title)
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
end

class Baz < Foo
end

Bar.title = 'Bar'
Baz.title = 'Baz'

Bar.title           #=> "Bar"
Bar.title = "Cat"

Baz.title           #=> "Baz"

Bar.class_variables #=> [:@@title]
Baz.class_variables #=> [:@@title]
Foo.class_variables #=> []

Foo.methods(false) #=> [:title=, :title]
Bar.methods(false) #=> []
Baz.methods(false) #=> []
```

If we were to execute `Bar`'s a getter before its setter, we'd get:

```
Bar.title #=> NameError: uninitialized class variable @@title in Bar
```

If desired, the class variables can be initialized (to `nil`, say) by adding the following to the class definition:

```
def self.inherited klass
  klass.class_variable_set(:@@title, nil)
end
```